# Colocar sexo, tipo de documento y nacionalidad en un input select html

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, mvc

Estoy realizando un sistema en donde tengo gestion de usuarios. En un formulario registro los datos personales de los usuarios. Tambien tengo la opcion de modificar esos datos personales que ya fueron registrados. Y lo que necesito es que al ingresar a realizar la modificacion de los datos personales en los campos sexo, nacionalidad y tipo de documento poder asignarle los datos registrados anteriormente en los select como opcion principal y ademas tambien tener las opciones para cada uno de ellos de manera de poder realizar la modificacion. Es decir si deseo modificar tipo de documento, poder en primera instancia mostrar en el select el tipo de DNI registrado en el Alta y tambien desplegar en el select las opciones (DNI, LC, LE, CI) y lo mismo para sexo () y nacionalidad. Mucho mejor si la opcion que esta precargada ya no se muestre en las demas opciones, es decir si una persona tiene registrado DNI, esta opcion se debe mostrar pero ya no debe aparecer en las opciones generales, solo debera aparecer LC, LE y CI. Y lo mismo para los otros campos. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Les comparto la clase Integrante

```
namespace VacunAR.Models
{
    public class Integrante
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DNI { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string TipoDocumento { get; set; }
        public string Nacionalidad { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime FechaNac { get; set; }

        public char Sexo { get; set; }
        public long Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Esta es la view de la modificacion. Solo lo tengo en tipos text y necesito poder utilizar los tipo select

```html
@model VacunAR.Models.Integrante
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ModificacionIntegrante</title>
    <link rel=StyleSheet href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel=StyleSheet href="~/Content/Background.css">
    <link rel=StyleSheet href="~/Content/Formulario.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="ModificacionIntegrante">
            <label> Id:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Id" value="@Model.Id" readonly />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> DNI:</label>
            <input type="text" name="DNI" value="@Model.DNI" readonly />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Apellido:</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido" value="@Model.Apellido" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Nombres:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" value="@Model.Nombre" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Tipo de Documento:</label>
            <input type="text" name="tipodocumento" value="@Model.TipoDocumento" maxlength="3" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Nacionalidad:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nacionalidad" value="@Model.Nacionalidad" maxlength="10" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaNac)
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Sexo:</label>
            <input type="text" name="sexo" value="@Model.Sexo" maxlength="1" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Telefono:</label>
            <input type="number" name="telefono" value="@Model.Telefono" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="@Model.Email" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Modificar" />
        </form>
        <br />
        <a href="/Home/MenuIntegrantes" title="Volver al Menu Integrantes"><img src="~/Contenido/volver.png"></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actualizo el post. Lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera:

```html
      <label> Tipo de Documento:</label>
            <select name="tipodocumento" required>
                <option hidden value="@Model.TipoDocumento" selected="selected">@Model.TipoDocumento</option>
                <option value="DNI"> DNI</option>
                <option value="LC"> LC</option>
                <option value="LE"> LE</option>
                <option value="CI"> CI</option>
            </select>
```

Le asigno el valor que ya viene cargado en la opcion principal y oculto ese valor de manera de no repetirlo en la lista desplegable.

Comment: Muestra la función del controlador

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef por tu atención. Saludos.